# Spark Word2Vec .save() method error

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to use Word2Vec method of Spark ML. However when I try to save the model object using both

model.save() or model.write().save() it throws me the following error.

```
---> 69 w2vdf,w2vmodel=word2Vec(sdf_cleaned)

<ipython-input-244-e0067f9959c6> in word2Vec(df)
     60 
     61     # Saving the model
---> 62     w2vmodel.write().save()
     63 
     64     return w2vdf,w2vmodel

AttributeError: 'Word2VecModel' object has no attribute 'write
```

Here is the code I wrote.

```
def word2Vec(df):
    """ This function takes in the data frame of the texts and finds the Word vector 
    representation of that

    """


    from pyspark.ml.feature import Tokenizer, Word2Vec


    # Carrying out the Tokenization of the text documents (splitting into words)

    tokenizer = Tokenizer(inputCol="desc", outputCol="tokenised_text")
    tokensDf = tokenizer.transform(df)

    # Implementing the word2Vec model

    word2Vec = Word2Vec(vectorSize=100, seed=42, inputCol="tokenised_text", outputCol="model")
    w2vmodel = word2Vec.fit(tokensDf)
    w2vdf=w2vmodel.transform(tokensDf)

    # Saving the model 
    w2vmodel.write().save()

    return w2vdf,w2vmodel
```

My second question is is it possible to get vector representation for each document and not individual words?. Like does Spark have Doc2Vec functionality implemented?

Comment: Just do `w2vmodel.save(sc, 'filename')`

Comment: Doesn't work. I did that. Same error.Wait. I need pass spark context. ok let me try that

Comment: Ok doesn't work. Same error. Spark Docs also doesn't say we need to pass spark context.

Comment: I was looking through previous open issues on GitHub and saw that, but perhaps I made a mistake. It does appear however that this is a known issue, and that there appears to be problems loading it as well. Is it not possible to `pickle` this model for use later? What version of Spark are you using as well?

Comment: It's a spark model. Can I pickle it?

Comment: You should be able to. It is strange that you can't save it since it is clearly mentioned here https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/ml/util/MLWritable.html as being able to be saved.

Comment: well there docs example of word2vec shows too that it can be saved. But I get the error

Comment: its a spark model object. While pickling it is throwing an error